# Separating numbers processed with a foreach conditional into specific category of numbers

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

This is a scenario: The $numbers array in the code below contains one thousand numbers(0 - 1000). I need to count how many of these numbers fit into each of the following categories:

1. how many of them are between 1 and 1000 inclusive,
2. how many of them are less than 1, and
3. how many of them are greater than 1000.

I have created a foreach loop to look at each number one after the other, but right now it's treating every number like it belongs in all three categories.

How do I get the counts correct? ie., how many numbers fit into the "Less than 1", "Between 1 and 1000", and "Greater than 1000" categories, respectively.

The current code:

```
$numbers = get_numbers();
$count_less_than_one           = 0;
$count_between_one_and_thousand = 0;
$count_greater_than_thousand    = 0;

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
   $count_less_than_one += 1;
   $count_between_one_and_thousand += 1;
   $count_greater_than_thousand += 1;
}
```

Comment: Where are your conditions? Are you expecting us to write them for you?

Answer (score 2):

Very simply just include the conditions. You can just use `if`

```
foreach ($numbers as $number) {

    if ($number < 1) $count_less_than_one += 1;

    else if ($number >= 1 && $number <= 1000) $count_between_one_and_thousand += 1;

    else $count_greater_than_thousand += 1;
}
```